# Enable zombie objects in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have an iOS app in Xamarin which crashes due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I wonder if is it possible enable zombie objects as an Xcode.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the **Enable Zombie Objects** checkbox in the tab called **diagnostics** of your current build's **run item**.

To run the zombies instrument, go to **profile** in the **project menu**, choose the MEmory group of instruments, and then select the **zombies** instrument.

So then when an object is unallocated, the system does not free it but marks it as a **zombie**.

Comment: M Aoun, I don't find the diagnostics tab you said.